# Magento: Full Action Name Handle not displaying

Tags: xml, magento, layout, magento-1.7

I am trying to add a string through a Mage_Core_Block_Text block on a page.
Here are my files:

Here is the Package Layout XML Update file local.xml (called last after all other handles have been applied to the Package Layout XML):

```
/var/www/magpractice/app/design/frontend/practice/default/layout/local.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <helloworld_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/text" name="our_message">
        <action method="setText"><text>Hello Mars</text></action>
      </block>
    </reference>
  </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

Here is the derived controller:

```
/var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

class Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

  public function indexAction() {

  }

}
```

and here is my config.xml from my module:

```
/var/www/magpractice/app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

<config>
  <modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld_Block</class>
        </helloworld>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Alanstormdotcom_Helloworld</module>
          <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
        </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

As far as what I gather no special blocks under the Block directory need be specified for this example.

When I go to http:// localhost/magpractice/helloworld/index/index I get a blank page.

The same is true if I replace  ...  with  ... .

Why? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `indexAction` method is missing the calls to `loadLayout` and `renderLayout`.

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

The `loadLayout` method parses the XML and instantiates block objects.

The `renderLayout` method calls the `toHtml` method on the root block.

Also, it's helpful to drop a `var_dump(__METHOD__);` into the controller action to make sure it's actually being called (vs. a blank page, which can mean so many different things)

Comment: Thanks. I got deceived by the fact that /var/www/magpractice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/controllers/IndexController.php is empty, but that's probably because it's not meant to be used as a derived controller. (?) Thought I could code my derived controller analogously. I was wrong.

Comment: Anyways, now I see the "Hello Mars" dumped in the middle of the page.